# Git clone repository throwing fatal error "Could not read username for 'http://<myTFSserver>:8080': terminal prompts disabled

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2017, team-explorer, git-credential-manager

Im running into a fatal error issue while doing clone from VS2017 for a git repository exist in TFS server. issue happening in windows 10 OS.

From visual studio team explorer -> manageConnection -> addTfsServer -> select git repo -> clone button click -> Fatal Error throwing.

"Could not read username for 'http://:8080': terminal prompts disabled"

Tried after deleting all TFS & git related entry in credential manager of control panel window. cleared Team foundation server cache folder as well.

Also visual studio launced in admin privillage mode.

git.log file entry while cloning ,

> 17:26:05.274484 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager get'
>
> 17:26:05.554802 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: '/c/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2017/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe' 'Username for '\''http://xxxxxxxxx:8080'\'': '

Comment: We are aware of this issue and are investigating.  The workaround right now is to update to version [1.18.4](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/1.18.4.0) of [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) and use the Git command line for the network operations until this can be sorted.

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgment . i have installed GCM 1.18.4 version and also tried to clone from Git command prompt. there im getting error message saying  Authentication failed while cloning the repository.

Comment: Im getting totally mad on this clone issue. everytime when it tries to clone , GIT-askpass.exe is trying to get username/password .but dont  know why the credential are not returning to askpass.exe. im glueless whether the problem is with my OS or Git-credential manager or TFS server.

Comment: Since this also repros from the command line with the latest GCM, let me direct you to the Git Credential Manager for Windows project for assistance.  There is a [template there to help collect the info to help diagnose the issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/new/choose).